# Gwt and MySql with RPC calls

Tags: java, mysql, gwt, label, rpc

So I have this Label "books" that has all books names, and every book has chapters... so I have 
another label for the chapters.
I want that when a book and a chapter are chosen, an RPC call will launch and get from the data base the chapter of the book the user wanted !

```
           books.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                int i;


                int selectedChapter = books.getSelectedIndex();
                if(selectedChapter != -1)
                {

                    chapters.clear();
                    for(i=0;i<bookChapters[selectedChapter];i++)
                    {
                        chapters.addItem("Chapter" + (i+1));


                    }


                }


            }

        });
```

RPC: Here I call for Book 1 Chapter 1 and it works.

```
                             //Book //Chapter
        rpcService.getChapterTxt(1, 1, new AsyncCallback<List<BibleTxt>>(){
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 

                {
              Window.alert("Failed getting Chapter");        
                }

            public void onSuccess(List<BibleTxt> result) 
            {
                int i = 0 ;
                String verseText ="";


                //Label verseLabel = new Label();
                PPanel chapterPar = new PPanel();
                HTML page= new HTML(verseText);
                for(i=0;i<result.size();i++)
                    {

                        verseText = result.get(i).getVerseText();
                        //verseLabel.setText(verseText);
                                page.setText(page.getText() + verseText);

                    } 
                chapterPar.add(page);
                p.add(chapterPar);

            }

        });
```

How do I use the RPC call in the Handler above ?

Comment: What does the `bookChapters` array represent? You're incrementing the index `i` until you reach `bookChapters[selectedChapter]`, but it's unclear to me what the purpose of this is.

Comment: On second look, I think perhaps the `selectedChapter` variable may be the index of the book, and that you're looping through for each chapter in the book adding a description to the `chapters` object. If that's the case then I think you may be trying to load every chapter for the selected book, in which case you'd want to invoke `getChapterTxt` for each chapter.

Comment: The loop works fine... I want to take the selectedChapter  and the bookChapters[selectedChapters] and send them through the rpcService.getChapter( selectedChapter , bookChapters[selectedChapter] , new Asychcall...)

Comment: Do you want to call the `getChapterTxt` server method multiple times? Or are you just trying to get one chapter when the user chooses a chapter? If you just want to get one chapter then just put the RPC call in the `onChange` method, after the `chapters.clear` call.

Comment: I thought about that and didnt like how the code looks , the compiler wanted rpcservice to be final and i dont know what is that ... if that is the only solution thank u and i hope final isnt global in java